# Handling "No Title" pages with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a problem when trying to access some urls, they randomly don't load and the page title shows "No Title" on the browser and don't show nothing on the print() and to properly load they need to be refreshed.

I'm trying to detect somehow these pages so they can be refreshed and accessed, here's a few examples of what I've tried so far:

```
def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    if not driver.title:
        print('Sem Titulo')
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass

def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    if driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") == '<html><head></head><body></body></html>':
        print('Sem Titulo')
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass

def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    if driver.title == 'Sem título':
        print('Sem Titulo')
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass
```

Since I'm pretty much on a dead end, I hope someone can help! Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's a picture of what's shown on the browser/test page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZbSB.png

Comment: Did you try to work with `try `and `except`? You could wrap your code in a loop, try to execute and hit the exception every time there is a "no title" page. The exception block could refresh the page and continue with the next iteration of your loop.

Comment: Here's what's shown on the browser: https://i.imgur.com/s9zMtRK.png

Comment: @trotta, it simply freezes on this part without even entering the proper handling, already tried too with try except and waits but no success so far.

Comment: Looks like it's not a proper url but rather a direct link to send a mail. Maybe checking the url before passing it to the selenium driver is a possibility?

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187949/discussion-on-question-by-vulture-handling-no-title-pages-with-selenium-python). If you are asked for additional information by a commenter, please [edit] that information into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of trials finally ended up solving the problem, it was actually a problem with the browser being used since I tested with a lot of versions of chrome and the driver.

The browser that worked was Opera/operadriver, and here's the function that actually worked handling the no title thing when it happened with Opera:

```
def no_title():
    sleep(2)
    doc_request = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    if doc_request == '<html><head></head><body></body></html>':
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the page title first and then store it in some variable like below :

```
someTitle = str(driver.title)
```

Then strip() it, strip() will remove the leading, the trailing spaces and check for empty quotes or None like below :

```
if someTitle.strip()=='' or someTitle.strip()==None:
```

Your updated method is below which will identify the 'No Title' pages :

```
def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    someTitle = str(driver.title)
    if someTitle.strip()=='' or someTitle.strip()==None:
        print('Sem Titulo')
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass
```

If your page is not getting refreshed then you can try the below code which will fetch the current url first then it will try to launch it again :

```
def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    someTitle = str(driver.title)
    if someTitle.strip()=='' or someTitle.strip()==None:
        print('Sem Titulo')
        currentURL = driver.current_url
        print(currentURL)
        driver.get(currentURL)
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass
```

If you have multiple windows/tabs opened then you need to switch to the particular tab for refreshing it using the windows handles, try the below code :

```
def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    someTitle = str(driver.title)
    if someTitle.strip()=='' or someTitle.strip()==None:
        print('Sem Titulo')
        current = driver.current_window_handle
        handles = driver.window_handles
        for handle in handles:
            if handle != current:
                driver.switch_to_window(handle)
                driver.refresh()
        driver.switch_to_window(current)
        sleep(2)
    else:
        pass
```

Or you can try the below :

```
def no_title():
    sleep(3)
    print('Sem Titulo')
    current = driver.current_window_handle
    handles = driver.window_handles
    for handle in handles:
        driver.switch_to_window(handle)
        someTitle = str(driver.title)
        if someTitle.strip()=='' or someTitle.strip()==None:
            driver.refresh()
    driver.switch_to_window(current)
    sleep(2)
else:
    pass
```